# Handling Division by Zero Error

Tags: c++, error-handling

So I posted code awhile back and the code runs fine. The code performs Addition, Subtraction and Multiplication to the two fractions then it finds out if the first fraction is smaller than the 2nd fraction, and lastly on the 2nd line it calculates the decimal form of the fraction. But I need to throw an exception that if the denominator is ever 0 the constructor will stop and throw an "Invalid Input" message, and then continues to the next set of inputs.

**Input**

```
2
2 0 4 5
1 2 3 4
```

**Expected Output**

```
Invalid input

5/4 -1/4 3/8 1/24 True
.50 .75
```

I was thinking that I could perform all the needed operations in int main and if the constructor throws out the error then print out "Invalid Input" else print out the operations. I'm just not sure how to do this with a class, I was thinking of using the "Catch and throw method" but I am not sure how to output a flag from the constructor.

**Constructor**

```
Rational(int n, int d)
{

        num = n;
        denom = d;

        if (denom == 0) {

            throw overflow_error("Divide by Zero");

        }

        normalize();



}
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
int case_count, a, b, c, d;
cin >> case_count;

for (int i = 0; i < case_count; ++i) {
    cout << "Case " << i << "\n";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    cin >> d;
    Rational frac1(a, b);
    Rational frac2(c,d);


    Rational frac1(a, b);
    Rational frac2(c, d);
    Rational add;
    Rational sub;
    Rational mult;
    Rational div;
    try {
        add = frac1 + frac2;
        sub = frac1 - frac2;
        mult = frac1 * frac2;
        div = frac1 / frac2;
        cout << add << " ";
        cout << sub << " ";
        cout << mult << " ";
        cout << div << " ";
        cout << (frac1 < frac2) << "\n";
        cout << frac1.toDecimal() << " ";
        cout << frac2.toDecimal() << "\n";

    }
    catch (overflow_error e) {
        cout << e.what();

    }
}

return 0;

}
```

If worst comes to worst I will just have int main check to see if any of them are 0 and print out invalid input. But its required that the constructor throws the exception to 0 denominator.

I'm not sure if the full code is needed its kinda lengthy but if you want to view it here is a link:

[Overloading Operator Rational Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222021/overloading-operator-rational-error)

Or if needs be I can post it. Really I'm just looking for some pseudocode or an idea of how to do this.

Comment: By putting it in the constructor, it will only be tested when you construct the object.  You need to do the `try` where you actually want to test for zero division.

Comment: @TriHard8 I thought about that only doing it when you are actually dividing by zero but the assignment specifically states that I need to do this inside this constructor which is why its a bit confusing to me.

Comment: The `throw` is inside the constructor, the `catch` is in main.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm oh I didn't know you could declare a catch outside of the scope where the throw is.

Comment: @Motorscooter: That's one of the primary reasons to have exceptions rather than just checking return values. Checking a return locally doesn't cost much, but needing to put the checks in at every level until someone handles it would be ugly. Exceptions let the intermediate stack layers (that don't know how to handle the problem) implicitly kick the problem up the line until someone volunteers to jump on that grenade (by using a `try`/`catch` to handle it), so their code doesn't need to put in code to retransmit exceptions they don't recognize, and can't do anything about.

Comment: So what's the question? Note that you should probably throw an object of a dedicated exception type, not just an `int` (it's hard to realize in another place that `int` means "division by zero" error).